# Slow matplotlib and ipywidgets image refresh

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I'm trying to scroll through some magnetic resonance slices using `plt.show()` and ipywidgets `interact()` function. I've found no problem by slowly moving the slider, but an important delay is found when sliding through the slices a little bit faster.

Here below is the code I'm using.

```
def dicom_animation(x, volume):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
    plt.imshow(volume['slices'][x]['pixel_array'], cmap=plt.cm.gray)


interact(dicom_animation, volume = fixed(a), x=IntSlider(round(len(a['slices'])/2,0), 0, (len(a['slices'])-1), layout=Layout(width='500px')))
```

And [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAkR6.png) is the result.

Is there anything I can do to make the sliding a little bit faster without this important delay?

Comment: I don't see any delay in your code

Comment: The plt image refreshing lags behind the cursor sliding

Answer (score 3):

Remaking the figure and calling `plt.imshow` are both pretty expensive operations which is what is slowing this down. Instead you need to use an interactive matplotlib backend and then use methods like `set_data`.

## Install ipympl

[ipympl](https://github.com/matplotlib/ipympl) is an interactive backend for matplotlbi that works in both jupyter nobteook and jupyterlab. It has a nice example notebook that explains things like how to interact with other widgets here: https://github.com/matplotlib/ipympl/blob/0.6.1/examples/ipympl.ipynb

Installing this is significantly easier for JupyterLab 3+ So:

```sh
pip install --upgrade jupyterlab ipympl
```

## manually create a slider

While `interact` is convenient it doesn't tend to play well with ipympl as it expects to completely regenerate the output everytime the slider changes.

```py
%matplotlib ipympl

# the rest of your setup code

fig, ax = plt.figure()
img = ax.imshow(volume['slices'][x]['pixel_array'], cmap=plt.cm.gray)

def update_plot(change):
    img.set_data(volume['slices'][change['new']['pixel_array']
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

x_slider = IntSlider(round(len(a['slices'])/2,0), 0, (len(a['slices'])-1)
x_slider.observe(update_plot, names='value')
```

## Use mpl-interactions

Manually setting up the slider can be a real hassle. So I wrote a library that to make it easy to control interactive plots using widgets. It handles creating the sliders and does all the correct things such as using `set_data` for you. It also will use matplotlib sliders if you aren't in a jupyter notebook so it is more portable.

In your case you would be interested in the [imshow example](https://mpl-interactions.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/imshow.html)
or depending on how your data is structured you may also be able to use the [hyperslicer](https://mpl-interactions.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/hyperslicer.html).

Your example would then be:

```py
%matplotlib ipympl

import mpl_interactions.ipyplot as iplt
# other setup stuff
volume = a

def f(x):
    return volume['slices'][x]['pixel_array']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
controls = iplt.imshow(f, cmap=plt.cm.gray, x = np.arange(0, len(a)-1))
```